# pyvdp - Python library for Visa Developer Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, api, e-commerce

I'm coming from PHP and recently started developing in Python. As a part of my self-study course, I developed a small library for access to [Visa Developer Program APIs](https://developer.visa.com) and [published](https://github.com/ppokrovsky/pyvdp/tree/8ffdd8a548b13c8f6918909cac94d6d8daa73781) it on Github. It is bundled with demo Django app. Here I'm sharing a module that implements an abstract connection to VDP.

I'd appreciate hearing your comments regarding the source code. Personally, I have a feeling that modules hierarchy could have been organized differently and maybe I'm overusing OOP approaches.

**visa/request.py**

```
import jsonpickle
import os
import requests

try:
    import urllib.parse as urllib_parse
except ImportError:
    # Python 2.7 compatibility
    from urllib import parse as urllib_parse

try:
    import configparser as parser
except ImportError:
    import ConfigParser as parser

from visa.exceptions import (VisaAccessDeniedError, VisaDuplicateTransactionError, VisaGeneralError,
                         VisaMessageValidationError, VisaNotFoundError, VisaTimeoutError, VisaUnauthenticatedError)


class VisaRequest:
    """
    Constructs a request to Visa API using provided transaction, resource, method and http verb.
    Request can be submitted with request() method, which returns a dictionary in following format:
    {'code': http_response_code, 'message': json-encoded content}
    This class is not assumed to be instantiated on its own (consider it abstract). Instead, every VISA API
    implementation must provide its own request class, inheriting from VisaRequest and providing a corresponding VISA
    API resource name as a `resource` argument value.
    """
    config = parser.ConfigParser()
    config_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'configuration.ini')
    config.read(config_file)

    def __init__(self, resource, api, method, http_verb):
        """
        :param resource: VISA API resource name
        :type resource: str
        :param api: VISA API api name
        :type api: str
        :param method: VISA API endpoint method
        :type method: str
        :param http_verb: VISA API HTTP verb
        :type http_verb: str
        """
        url = self.config.get('VISA', 'url')
        version = self.config.get('VISA', 'version')
        self.user_id = self.config.get('VISA', 'username')
        self.password = self.config.get('VISA', 'password')
        self.cert = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), self.config.get('VISA', 'cert'))
        self.key = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), self.config.get('VISA', 'key'))

        self.api_endpoint = url + "/" + resource + "/" + api + "/" + version + "/" + method
        self.http_verb = http_verb

        # FIXME: Hardcoded request/response in json format
        self.headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }

        self.result = None

    def send(self, transaction=None):
        """
        Sends a Transaction object to VISA using self.api_endpoint field and corresponding http verb.
        :param transaction: instance of VisaTransaction
        :type transaction: VisaTransaction
        :return: dict
        """
        transaction = self.__to_vd(transaction)

        result = requests.request(
            self.http_verb,
            self.api_endpoint,
            data=transaction,
            cert=(self.cert, self.key),
            auth=(self.user_id, self.password),
            headers=self.headers
        )

        return self.__response({'code': result.status_code, 'message': result.json()})

    @staticmethod
    def __response(result):
        """
        Processes a response from Visa Direct API.
        Depending on http code in response, either returns a result or raises corresponding app-level exception.
        :param result: Response from VISA
        :type result: dict
        :return result: Resulting dictionary
        :raises VisaTimeoutError, VisaDuplicateTransactionError, VisaMessageValidationError, VisaUnauthenticatedError,
                VisaAccessDeniedError, VisaNotFoundError, VisaGeneralError
        """
        code = result['code']

        if code == 200:
            return result
        elif code == 202:
            raise VisaTimeoutError(result=result)
        elif code == 303:
            raise VisaDuplicateTransactionError(result=result)
        elif code == 400:
            raise VisaMessageValidationError(result=result)
        elif code == 401:
            result = {'message': {'errorMessage': str(result['message'])}}
            raise VisaUnauthenticatedError(result=result)
        elif code == 403:
            raise VisaAccessDeniedError(result=result)
        elif code == 404:
            raise VisaNotFoundError(result=result)
        else:
            raise VisaGeneralError(result=result)

    @staticmethod
    def __to_vd(transaction=None):
        """
        Serializes VisaTransaction object to json string.
        :param transaction: instance of VisaTransaction.
        :return: json
        """
        if not transaction:
            return
        else:
            return jsonpickle.encode(transaction, unpicklable=False)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code overall looks clean, there will always be debates on writing classes or not (both approaches have great reasoning behind them, of course):

- [Stop Writing Classes (PyCon 2012)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)
- [Start Writing More Classes](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/2/13/moar-classes/) (2013)

Some things you can improve:

- the status code handling. Build a *mapping between status codes and exception types* - this would help to make the code more modular, configurable and concise, something like:

  ```
  ERROR_CODES = {
      202: VisaTimeoutError,
      303: VisaDuplicateTransactionError,
      400: VisaMessageValidationError,
      401: VisaUnauthenticatedError,
      403: VisaAccessDeniedError,
      404: VisaNotFoundError
  }
  if code == 200:
      return result
  else:
      raise ERROR_CODES.get(code, VisaGeneralError)(result=result)
  ```
- you can avoid some nestedness in the `__to_vd()` method:

  ```
  if not transaction:
      return

  return jsonpickle.encode(transaction, unpicklable=False)
  ```
- since you are repeatedly getting the current directory name and, it is not going to change, do it once beforehand and reuse:

  ```
  CUR_DIR_NAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)
  ```
- I would also initialize a session via [`requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) in the class constructor, define the `session.headers`, `session.auth` and other required parameters. Then, when you will make API requests using `self.session`, all of the parameters you've initially set will be automatically applied. This will also have a positive performance impact:

  > ..if you're making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP
  >   connection will be reused, which can result in a significant
  >   performance increase
- follow the [`PEP8` import organization guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

Comment: `urljoin` signature in 3.6 assumes 3 arguments: `def urljoin(base, url, allow_fragments=True)`, so I guess you have to do concat anyway?

Comment: @paulus ah, you are right, my bad. It's possible to do it "recursively" with `urljoin()`, but would overcomplicate things I guess, will remove the advice. Thanks.

Comment: for the record - i don't like concat either. I'm guessing something like `'/'.join([url, api, resource, method])` would be a nice thing. But I've googled it around, apparently there's no pythonic solution for proper url joining, since everyone is doing it differently.